# Change rows to columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT ItemMaster.ERPItemCode, DistributorStock.Qty
FROM DistributorStock INNER JOIN
ItemMaster ON DistributorStock.ItemMasterId = ItemMaster.Id
WHERE (DistributorStock.DistributionCenterId = 2)
```

Results are attached:

[image]

I want to change the query to show `Item Code` in columns, not in rows.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sample please for my example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator. If your list of codes is dynamic and you don't know the full list in time of writing the query, you have to use dynamic pivot, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query).

Sample:

```
select 'TotalQty', [DHS20], [DHP12], [DHP10], [DHL12], ...
from
(SELECT ItemMaster.ERPItemCode, DistributorStock.Qty
    FROM DistributorStock
    JOIN ItemMaster ON DistributorStock.ItemMasterId = ItemMaster.Id
    WHERE (DistributorStock.DistributionCenterId = 2)
) src
pivot
(sum(src.Qty)
for src.ERPItemCode in ([DHS20], [DHP12], [DHP10], [DHL12], ...)
) as pvt
```

You can replace `sum` aggregate function with any other as you wish. For dynamic query, you have to build the query at runtime, building the lists of columns from some other query. You can find how to concatenate strings in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string).